# How do i modify TakeProfit of all current open position using OrderModify()?

Tags: mql4

I have opened up to five buy trades with their individual take profit. I want to change the take profit of the first four buy trades to the take profit of number five buy trade. `modifyAllBuyOrdTP()` is the function created to modify the take profit while `findTpL_BuyOrd()` function will get the take profit of the last trade that just finished opened. It is not working in strategy tester. I will be grateful to anyone that can help me on this problem. Thank you in advance.

```
void modifyAllBuyOrdTP(){
       
       if(CountTradesBuy()>=2){
          for(int l_pos_4 = OrdersTotal() - 1; l_pos_4 >= 0; l_pos_4--)
          {
             OrderSelect(l_pos_4, SELECT_BY_TICKET);
             if(OrderSymbol() != Symbol() || OrderMagicNumber() != MagicNumber)
                continue;
             if(OrderTakeProfit() == findTpL_BuyOrd())
                continue;
             if(OrderStopLoss() == 0 && OrderTakeProfit() != findTpL_BuyOrd() && OrderSymbol() == Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber){
               if(OrderType() == OP_BUY){
                   ModifyStopsByPrice(OrderTicket(),0,findTpL_BuyOrd());//Print(" b tp ",findTpL_BuyOrd());
               }
             }
          }
      }
   }
    
double findTpL_BuyOrd(){
   double l_ord_TP = 0;
      for(int l_pos_4 = OrdersTotal() - 1; l_pos_4 >= 0; l_pos_4--)
      {
         OrderSelect(l_pos_4, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES);
         if(OrderSymbol() != Symbol() || OrderMagicNumber() != MagicNumber)
            continue;
         if(OrderTakeProfit() == 0)
            continue;
         if(OrderTakeProfit()!=0 && OrderSymbol() == Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber){
           if(OrderType() == OP_BUY){
               l_ord_TP = OrderTakeProfit();
               break;
           }
         }
      }
  return l_ord_TP;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `modifyAllBuyOrdTP()` function you should select orders by `SELECT_BY_POS` if you iterating over them.